# Why Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1 reported 305 code error on Ratis consensus?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I tried to execute Apache IoTDB V1.0.1, a 305 code error appeared, and the message is `cannot fetch schema, status is: 301, msg is: Execute FragmentInstance failed: Ratis request failed`. I only know that Ratis consensus can be supported in IoTDB, but I don't know why here this reflected unconnected. What may be the reason for this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like this is a bug and has already been solved in later version. You can upgrade to Version 1.1.0 of Apache IoTDB and see if this error has been solved.